# Calling a function from typescript

Tags: typescript

In an object, I need to call out to a function on that page that is not part of the typescript file. As typescript doesn't know about it, it fails to compile.

How do I tell typescript that the call is fine and to let it through? function name is MY_PERSONAL_FUNCTION in this example

```
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        error: (e) => { MY_PERSONAL_FUNCTION (e); },
```

Comment: You need to include a `.d.ts` file for Kendo.

Comment: I have included it, but MY_PERSONAL_FUNCTION is my function. Typescript fails on MY_PERSONAL_FUNCTION as it is not defined.

Comment: if you have written this file else where, you can export the function from your js file and import it in your typescript class.

Comment: How do I just ignore the typescript error. This is a function that is on the page that is added by another project magically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going for quick and dirty, you can just add `declare function` to the top of your script.  This will tell TypeScript the function has been created somewhere else.

```
declare function MY_PERSONAL_FUNCTION(e: any);

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    error: (e) => { MY_PERSONAL_FUNCTION (e); },
```